# Flex PCB Max Current Handling Capacity

Tags: voltage, pcb, current, pcb-design

I want to design a board using Flex PCB. I can calculate the maximum current I can pass through a path on the PCB, but I couldn't find any documentation on how much current and voltage can pass through the flexible PCB. How can I learn this information?

Comment: Generally, the free software Saturn PCB toolkit is a good start, but I don't see any flexible PCBs listed.

Comment: Behold, The BIBLE:
https://www.ipc.org/TOC/IPC-2223E-toc.pdf

IPC-2221, 2222, and  2223 are amazing resources to have and study if you are designing boards on a regular basis. I encourage you to buy (or find) the spec and give it a look. Flex PCBs have some interesting quirks

Comment: I read the IPC-2221 document, I saw some calculations related to the current calculation for the standard pcb, but I cannot access the ipc-2223 document, can I use the standard pcb calculations? Is there a difference in current carrying capacity between Flex and Standard pcb?